# How can I combine information in two different classes to show the result in a ListBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

My program contains two different classes. I want to combine the values of both, only to show the resulting information in a `ListBox`. The information is stored in a database, the classes in my code have been created by a LINQ to SQL `DataClass`.

**First class (ReactorParameters)**

This class contains information about the reactor at a specific time, like the flame temperature, amount of oil, amount of air...

*Class definition:*

```
public class ReactorParameters
{
    public TimeSpan Time
    { get; set; }

    public double Temperature
    { get; set; }

    public double Oil
    { get; set; }

    public double Air
    { get; set; }
}
```

*Example data:*

[image: ReactorParameters sample data]

**Second class (ProductInformation)**

The `ProductInformation` class stores information about which product has been produced by the reactor at what time period.

*Class definition:*

```
public class ProductInformation
{
    public TimeSpan Time_From
    { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan Time_To
    { get; set; }

    public Product Product
    { get; set; }
}
```

*Example data:*

[image: ProductInformation sample data]

**What do I want the result to look like?**

What I want to acheive is to combine the reactor parameters with the product that has been produced at the given time.

[image: The combined data]

**This is an easy task. Why are you asking?**

Of course, I can make a new class, create an instance for each `ReactorParameters` and store the relevant `Product` in it. But since this is just for UI purposes (I don't need the extra class for anything else), I'm not sure if there is a better way to reach the goal. I've heard about `CompositeCollection` and `CollectionView`, but I'm not sure if this is helpful for me.

So, is there any other way than a separate class to populate my `ListBox`?

Comment: Do you want that in a `listbox` (only one column) or `grid` (multiple columns)?

Comment: @ANewGuyInTown I've already styled a `ListBox` with a custom `DataTemplate`. This `DataTemplate` contains a `Grid` with many columns. I've placed a `TextBox` in each cell, so the result looks like a readonly `DataGrid`. My `ListBox` is already showing all `ReactorParameters`, but the `ProductInformation` are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create view class to bind it.

Try following code (I replaced `Product` with `string` for test):

```
public class ReactorParameters
{
    public TimeSpan Time { get; set; }

    public double Temperature { get; set; }

    public double Oil { get; set; }

    public double Air { get; set; }
}

public class ProductInformation
{
    public TimeSpan Time_From { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan Time_To { get; set; }

    public string Product { get; set; }
}

public class ReactorView
{
    public ReactorParameters Parameters { get; set; }
    public ProductInformation Product { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// entry point
/// </summary>
public void Test()
{
    Random rnd = new Random(1000);

    // random parameters
    List<ReactorParameters> parameters = (from i in Enumerable.Range(0, 24)
                                          select new ReactorParameters
                                          {
                                              Time = TimeSpan.FromHours(i),
                                              Temperature = rnd.NextDouble() * 50.0,
                                              Oil = rnd.NextDouble() * 20.0,
                                              Air = rnd.NextDouble() * 30.0,
                                          }).ToList();

    // product information
    List<ProductInformation> products = (from i in Enumerable.Range(0, 4)
                                         select new ProductInformation
                                         {
                                             Time_From = TimeSpan.FromHours(i * 6),
                                             Time_To = TimeSpan.FromHours(i * 6 + 6),
                                             Product = "Product " + (char)('A' + i),
                                         }).ToList();


    // combine
    var result = parameters.SelectMany(param => from product in products
                                                where param.Time >= product.Time_From && param.Time <= product.Time_To
                                                select new ReactorView
                                                {
                                                    Parameters = param,
                                                    Product = product
                                                });

    // alternative query
    var resultAlt = from param in parameters
                 from product in products
                 where param.Time >= product.Time_From && param.Time <= product.Time_To
                 select new ReactorView
                 {
                     Parameters = param,
                     Product = product
                 };

    // print result
    foreach (var item in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0,-5} {1,-8:0.00} {2,-8:0.00} {3,-8:0.00} {4,-10}",
            item.Parameters.Time, item.Parameters.Temperature, item.Parameters.Air, item.Parameters.Oil, item.Product.Product);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so from what I see, creating a 'View' class is the way to go. I wasn't 100% sure about that. Thanks for your code example, the SelectMany query is neat - I should use it more often.

Comment: I added alternative query with 2 conditional selects, result is same.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion i should go for an new class containing those classes as a property. This way allows you to extend in the furture in case you need some more properties.

```
public class ProductReactorModel
{
    public ReactorParameters ReactorParameters {get;set;}
    public ProductInformation ProductInformation {get;set;}
}
```

Then create a list of the new created class `List<ProductReactorModel>`. Bind this list to the ListBox. With this class you can access both classes and properties to display in you're ListBox. Binding on the following way inside the ListBox.

```
{Binding ReactorParameters.Time}
```